# Are there differences between the three Luchadors beyond their body slam style?

Tags: burrito-bison-launcha

So my brother and I have been playing Burrito Bison: Launcha Libre for a fair bit of time now, and we believe that there are more differences between the three luchadores (Burrito Bison, Pineapple Spank, and El Pollo) aside from their different body slam mechanics.

Currently, we think that Burrito Bison is the best at breaking doors; Pineapple Spank is best at eating cake; and El Pollo has the highest bounce. These thoughts are educated guesses we got from our observations of playing the game, not from anything concrete.

So if there are any concrete sources out there about secondary differences, what are the actual differences between the three aside from body slam mechanics?

Answer (score 2):

Burrito Bison : If you are at a certain height, Bison will slam anything that he hits on the ground, so you basically don't need to worry about him hitting the police or the ground because he won't lose any speed.

Pineapple Spank : Nothing much. You just need to save some rockets so that she will grab the more special gummy bears.

El Pollo : I like this hero because he can really earn some big $$$! When you hold the rocket launcher thing, he will elevate himself and then slam down. Try using that technique just before you hit the ground where there's lots of gummy bears.It will hit them all, getting all the money and then slam into the ground again (more money yay).

Hope it helps

Comment: I did say, "differences between the three *aside from body slam mechanics,*" so listing the different slam mechanics doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score -2):

I love pineapple spank, because not only she grabs and pulls, but she's so good at slamming into people. When I got her, I was able to travel farther and I was able to get good crits on bosses. Trust me, you're going to like pineapple spank. Lots of people think she is not good but she's more than a girl with a grappling hook.